# How do I redirect_to with Authorization headers in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, header, authorization

Trying to pass Oauth access token via headers to another url (May or may not be another domain).

haml code-

```
%a{:href => "/external_redirect?user_id=#{@user['id']}", :id => 'external_url' }
```

controller -

```
def external_redirect

 external_url = "http://external.abc.com:3008/consumerlogin?user_id=#{params["user_id"]}"

 response.headers["Authorization"] = "OAuth #{cookies[ :access_token ]}"

 redirect_to external_url

end
```

Am I doing this right? The header is not being sent to the external_url.

Answer (score 1):

The redirect will cause the client to start a new request.

You have the response headers until the moment the browser starts serving the redirect.

After that moment, you can't pass/transfer these headers to the new request originated by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is not with the headers not being sent, but with your header values. OAuth's header to provide your access token looks like this:

```
Authorization: Bearer ACCESS-TOKEN
```

You have `OAuth` instead of `Bearer`. Try to change your code to:

```
response.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer #{cookies[ :access_token ]}"
```